# Spring MVC List Values Returned Unchanged

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, list

I am struggling with getting the changed list values in my JSP to get returned to the MVC controller. The values are displayed fine, but changes do not show up in the ModelAttribute when the form is submitted (any non-list values that are changed DO show up when submitted). Here is an abbreviated version of the relevant code:

JSP:

```
<c:forEach items="${poForm.poDetail}" varStatus="i">
...
<!-- Product Description -->
<td class="leftAlign"  >
  <form:input path="poDetail[${i.index}].description"  />
</td>
```

BACKING FORM:

```
public class POForm {
  private List<PurchaseOrderDetail> poDetail;
...
}
```

PURCHASEORDERDETAIL:

```
public class PurchaseOrderDetail implements Comparable<PurchaseOrderDetail>{
    private String partNumber; // alpha-numeric part number (vendor's)
private String description; // Product name/description
... remaining properties are non-complex
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/savePO",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView savePO(@ModelAttribute("poForm") POForm poForm, final       
     HttpServletRequest request) {
.... "examine the poForm here and items of poDetail are unchanged"
}
```

any suggestions to try??

Comment: Do you have setter and getter for poDetail and description attribute?

Comment: Yes. I did not include them in the code to keep it simpler.

Comment: Do you have any other @ModelAttribute annotated methods in this controller - It has to retrieve the old values from somewhere right

Comment: First try to use a tool like FireBug to check whether the updated details are transmitted to the server or not. This will help the decide where to seach the the problem (jsp or controller)

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware that I could do that in FireBug. Indeed, that uncovered the issue. I had another form on the page that was being submitted instead of the form I wanted (long story short, JQuery novice). Once I corrected that, the changed values in the List appeared, as expected. I would give you credit for the answer but your answer below was not what I was looking for. How about a big "Thanks a lot"?

Answer (score 0):

I rememeber that I have had some problems like this some time ago. And when I remember right, the problem was gone after changing the backing from´s `List` to an `array`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ralph, I discovered that Spring MVC List values were not being returned because I was inadvertently submitting the wrong form. Once I corrected that, then the List values were being returned as expected.